# jQuery deferred assign value doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I have this code: my first validation is that I tried to check if username is not null then I have a ajax validation which validate if username is already existing. however, when I tried to assign my variable inside the callback function the value that I assigned doesn't work..

`isValid` initiale value is `true`.. if `username` is existing I want to assigned `false` on it.. but the value doesn't change..

when I tried `console.log(isValid)` it is still true.. thanks in advance..

```
function validateStep1(){
       var isValid = true; 
       // Validate Username
       var un = $('#username').val();
       if(!un && un.length <= 0){
         isValid = false;
         $('#msg_username').html('(Please fill username)').show();
       }else{
           //username ajax validation
           var $check_username;
           var $form = $('#create_user_form').data('url');
           var $url = $form + "employee_c/username_validation";
           $.when(ajax_validation($url,un)).done(function(){
              if(_gbValidateSuccess){
                 $('#msg_username').html('(Username is already existing!)').show();
                 isValid = false;
              }else{
                $('#msg_username').html('').hide();
              }
           });
       }
     console.log(isValid); //still true.. but should be false instead..
}
```

Comment: This happens due to async behavior, try to print where you asigned value

Comment: @NitinDhomse yes it seems this happened because of the async.. when I tried to console.log inside the callback function I can see the `isValid` variable is false.. but When I tried to echo it outside it stays `true`... what would be the best solution for this?

Comment: Use promise and set your value in resolve()

Comment: @NitinDhomse can you give me some example to work on? sorry, i'm really not that good when it comes to jquery deferred function..

Answer (score 0):

Use Promise, its so simple and nice for async call (download and include promise js)

```
 function validateStep1(){
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
       var un = $('#username').val();
           if(!un && un.length <= 0){
             reject(); // it will return false
             $('#msg_username').html('(Please fill username)').show();
           }else{
               //username ajax validation
               var $check_username;
               var $form = $('#create_user_form').data('url');
               var $url = $form + "employee_c/username_validation";
               $.when(ajax_validation($url,un)).done(function(){
                  if(_gbValidateSuccess){
                     $('#msg_username').html('(Username is already existing!)').show();
                     isValid = false;
                     reject(); // it will return false
                  }else{
                    $('#msg_username').html('').hide();
                    resolve(); //it will return true
                  }
               });
           }

     });
    }
```

//add this code for promise js

```
<script>
    (function(t){function z(){for(var a=0;a<g.length;a++)g[a][0](g[a][1]);g=[];m=!1}function n(a,b){g.push([a,b]);m||(m=!0,A(z,0))}function B(a,b){function c(a){p(b,a)}function h(a){k(b,a)}try{a(c,h)}catch(d){h(d)}}function u(a){var b=a.owner,c=b.state_,b=b.data_,h=a[c];a=a.then;if("function"===typeof h){c=l;try{b=h(b)}catch(d){k(a,d)}}v(a,b)||(c===l&&p(a,b),c===q&&k(a,b))}function v(a,b){var c;try{if(a===b)throw new TypeError("A promises callback cannot return that same promise.");if(b&&("function"===
            typeof b||"object"===typeof b)){var h=b.then;if("function"===typeof h)return h.call(b,function(d){c||(c=!0,b!==d?p(a,d):w(a,d))},function(b){c||(c=!0,k(a,b))}),!0}}catch(d){return c||k(a,d),!0}return!1}function p(a,b){a!==b&&v(a,b)||w(a,b)}function w(a,b){a.state_===r&&(a.state_=x,a.data_=b,n(C,a))}function k(a,b){a.state_===r&&(a.state_=x,a.data_=b,n(D,a))}function y(a){var b=a.then_;a.then_=void 0;for(a=0;a<b.length;a++)u(b[a])}function C(a){a.state_=l;y(a)}function D(a){a.state_=q;y(a)}function e(a){if("function"!==
            typeof a)throw new TypeError("Promise constructor takes a function argument");if(!1===this instanceof e)throw new TypeError("Failed to construct 'Promise': Please use the 'new' operator, this object constructor cannot be called as a function.");this.then_=[];B(a,this)}var f=t.Promise,s=f&&"resolve"in f&&"reject"in f&&"all"in f&&"race"in f&&function(){var a;new f(function(b){a=b});return"function"===typeof a}();"undefined"!==typeof exports&&exports?(exports.Promise=s?f:e,exports.Polyfill=e):"function"==
    typeof define&&define.amd?define(function(){return s?f:e}):s||(t.Promise=e);var r="pending",x="sealed",l="fulfilled",q="rejected",E=function(){},A="undefined"!==typeof setImmediate?setImmediate:setTimeout,g=[],m;e.prototype={constructor:e,state_:r,then_:null,data_:void 0,then:function(a,b){var c={owner:this,then:new this.constructor(E),fulfilled:a,rejected:b};this.state_===l||this.state_===q?n(u,c):this.then_.push(c);return c.then},"catch":function(a){return this.then(null,a)}};e.all=function(a){if("[object Array]"!==
            Object.prototype.toString.call(a))throw new TypeError("You must pass an array to Promise.all().");return new this(function(b,c){function h(a){e++;return function(c){d[a]=c;--e||b(d)}}for(var d=[],e=0,f=0,g;f<a.length;f++)(g=a[f])&&"function"===typeof g.then?g.then(h(f),c):d[f]=g;e||b(d)})};e.race=function(a){if("[object Array]"!==Object.prototype.toString.call(a))throw new TypeError("You must pass an array to Promise.race().");return new this(function(b,c){for(var e=0,d;e<a.length;e++)(d=a[e])&&"function"===
    typeof d.then?d.then(b,c):b(d)})};e.resolve=function(a){return a&&"object"===typeof a&&a.constructor===this?a:new this(function(b){b(a)})};e.reject=function(a){return new this(function(b,c){c(a)})}})("undefined"!=typeof window?window:"undefined"!=typeof global?global:"undefined"!=typeof self?self:this);
    </script>
```

Comment: did you included promise js?

Comment: yes..., my temporary fix for this is to use `async:false`... is it okay to use it? my validation is not `asynchronous` in the first place..

Comment: @SamTengWong its ok, but not correct solution because, async call blocks user interaction and ui rendering, so its a bad practice

Comment: because my situation is that I have a steps and on every step of my slide... you can't proceed or go backwards if the current step hasn't validated yet.... I've tried your code but seems to have an error...

Comment: same problem I have faced and implemented above solution, I am sure that this should work, need to figure out error

Comment: hello sir, here's the link where I downloaded the `promise.js`. https://github.com/stackp/promisejs

Comment: Hello sir, I've tried your code still has an error on it!... same error...

Comment: Hello sir, it says `uncaught(in promise) undefined`. when I click the error line: it points me to `reject()`.

Comment: Could you please, Google it to resolve this issue I hope this will resolve